# Twig overriding parent variables

Tags: blocks, 8, theming

I want to override the block.html.twig 'classes' variable in my block--system-branding-block.html.twig which extends block.html.twig. I tried to set the 'classes' inside block--system-branding-block.html but this didn't work.

**block.html.twig**

```
{%
 set classes = [
  'block',
  'block-' ~ configuration.provider|clean_class,
  'block-' ~ plugin_id|clean_class,
]
%}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
 {{ title_prefix }}
 {% if label %}
   <h2{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</h2>
 {% endif %}
 {{ title_suffix }}
 {% block content %}
   {{ content }}
 {% endblock %}
</div>
```

**block--system-branding-block.html.twig**

```
{% extends "block.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}
  {% if site_name %}
    <div class="site-name">
     <a href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home">{{ site_name }}</a>
   </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if site_slogan %}
   <div class="site-slogan">{{ site_slogan }}</div>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I want to put another entry in the classes variable just for the block--system-branding-block.html.twig witch extends the block.html.twig

Comment: That doesn't look like your full block--system-branding.block.html.twig, I don't see an `extends` in there. Please paste the complete code. Or that's why it's not working :)

Comment: @Cottser You are right there is an extends, I removed the comment block for simplicity and I accidentally removed the exteds too. But it's there in my code. Doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Is `classes` inside or out of a twig block?

Comment: *...I just want to override them for the parrent template.*. Well, it sounds a bit confused. I'm almost sure you want override from child template, instead parent template.

Comment: @felipsmartins I want to put another entry in the classes variable just for the block--system-branding-block.html.twig witch extends the block.html.twig

Comment: @Achilles Take a look on the below answer.

Comment: @felipsmartins Yep, I understand now ... the problem is that the "set classes" is out of a twig block in the parent template, and this is what i want to override.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32168/discussion-between-achilles-and-felipsmartins).

Comment: @Achilles It's okay if the main variable is outside of block (that is your case), but so that overrride/re-assign the expression MUST is inside a block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite the approach you had in mind (modifying the classes variable) but I would recommend you [do as Bartik does](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21bartik%21templates%21block--system-branding-block.html.twig/8) and work with the Attribute object instead:

```
{% extends "block.html.twig" %}

{% set attributes = attributes.addClass('new-class-goes-here') %}

{% block content %}
  {% if site_name %}
    <div class="site-name">
     <a href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home">{{ site_name }}</a>
   </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if site_slogan %}
   <div class="site-slogan">{{ site_slogan }}</div>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I think the key thing here is that the variable you are modifying is initialized (and used) *outside* of the twig block. If the variable were initialized inside the twig block then I can see needing to override it inside the child templates's twig block as well.

More on working with Attributes in templates here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2513632

Comment: This approach works. It extends the parent's classes with the new class instead of overriding them completely.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "override" any variables from non-block.
In fact, what you must re-assign the `classes` array from inside a block in the child template (or in the same), like this:

```
<!-- block.html.twig -->

{% set classes = ['foo', 'bar'] %}


<!-- block--system-branding-block.html.twig  -->

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block someblock %}
   {% set classes = classes | merge(['another-classe']) %}
{% endblock %}
```

On-line code working: http://twigfiddle.com/rav5tx

Comment: I try this but it doesn't seem to work :(  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Achilles Read again. I'm sure you're doing it wrong...

Comment: @felipsmartins there is no `extends` statement in your Twigfiddle. It does not seem to work when a template is extended

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this in your .theme file:

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_block__system_branding_block(&$variables)
{
$variables['attributes']['class'][] = "yourotherclass";
}
```

That's if you use the standard block.html.twig - Code you are showing above seems to be not standard block.html.twig

Comment: In general classes should not be added via preprocess in D8.

Comment: Maybe you can give an explanation why it should not be done via preprocess and an example how to do it in TWIG. I did not find an easy way to add it to {{ attributes }} directly in block.html.twig. Example from felipsmartins is surely working in TWIG, but is not especially for the block.html.twig more generally I think.

Comment: @StefanKorn Yes, I know there is a preprocess function for this, I was wondering if it is possible with Twig!! Thanks anyway.

Comment: @StefanKorn see https://www.drupal.org/node/2325067 for more background on classes being moved to templates rather than preprocess. From that change record: "This change gives themers greater control over class usage, without having to use preprocess functions and complex logic to remove or add classes."